# TypeScript ability to use a type's value and derive other value from keying off of type/interface map

Tags: typescript

```
type ListThemes =
  | "projects"
  | "data"
  | "alerts"
  | "jobs";

type ListDataType = {
  projects: ProjectListFieldsTypeMap;
  data: DataListFieldsTypeMap;
  alerts: AlertsListFieldsTypeMap;
  jobs: JobListFieldsTypeMap;
};

type ListProps = {
  theme: ListThemes;
  data: DERIVED_TYPE_HERE;
};
```

`DERIVED_TYPE_HERE` would be the value of `ListDataType[theme]`

Have made attempts to more directly tie `ListThemes` to the keys in `ListDataType`, but was not able to do so and still directly create a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: so basically you want if `theme` is `"alerts"` then type of `"data"` is `AlertsListFieldsTypeMap` etc etc?

Comment: And what is `"entities"` supposed to map to?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w1ypAw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this with generics might achieve your goal as I'm reading it:

```
type ListProps<T extends ListThemes> = {
  theme: T;
  data: ListDataType[T];
};
```

and you could also condense it and get rid of type `ListThemes` like:

```
type ListProps<T extends keyof ListDataType> = {
  theme: T;
  data: ListDataType[T];
};
```

but this won't work with the code you've given as `GraftListThemes` isn't defined, so I'm not sure what it's referring to, and `entities` doesn't map to anything in `ListDataType`.